# "Attach socket" with Oculus Interaction SDK

Tags: unity, c#, virtual-reality, oculus

I'm trying to recreate the "attach socket" (XRSocketInteractor) from Unity's XR Interaction Toolkit.

Has anyone had any success? I've read through the documentation but can't come up with a simple way to do this. I've even tried writing my own script with an `OnTriggerEnter()` using both

`grabInteractable.AddSelectingInteractor(grabInteractor);` and `grabInteractor.Select();`

but still haven't got a complete snap attach..

I've gotten the grabbable object to turn green (be Selected) seen with the "Interactable Debug Visual" script but the object doesn't "auto move" to the transform point and I'd rather see if there is indeed a proper way to do it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now the "Snap Interaction" (or "drop zone") included in the SDK https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/unity-isdk-drop-zone-interaction/

Comment: This answer would be even better if it briefly summarized how to use this to solve the problem.

Comment: When someone figures that out I'll edit my answer, their own docs are convoluted as they are